# Is there a way to point jar libraries in a different location from a war in tomcat 8 to reduce war size?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, gradle

I have my web service made in Grails/Gradle which contains a lot of dependencies jars making the war size heavy which is deployed in  tomcat8. Is there any way that my war would use the dependencies from separate location so that my war would be free from these bulk dependency libraries.

Comment: Disk is cheap.  Why do this?  There's no harm in having a WAR with JARs in it.  You should not do this.

Comment: @duffymo disk is cheap, so is the company.

Comment: @sgin - probably not.  Any run of the mill PC you can buy would have enough disk to not require such practices.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven for instance you could do something. In all dependecies you dont want to include into your WAR file add the  tag.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then when maven build your WAR file, a folder lib-provided will generated, you can get rid of this folder and reduce the size of your war.

All those dependecies you dont want to include in your WAR, you should place them into your TOMCAT_HOME/lib and Tomcat will check the libraries of your project and also the jars located in this folder.

**IMPORTANT**: I would never do this option, because you are doing your WAR dependent to some specific application server, if you try to deploy your WAR in another Server, wont work, if you update your maven dependencies you have to manually update them in your application server.

So I highly would go for another option rather than this, and I would keep your WAR independant to any application server.

Answer (score -1):

Check your project into Git (of course without jars) and create a script on your server to check it out, build it (with Maven or Gradle) and deploy it to Tomcat.

Have a look at a Continous Integration system like Bamboo or [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), to do that automatically.

Comment: How does this reduce the war size?